# How to make heatmap more beautiful?

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm using RStudio's PDF export function to generate PDFs. Unfortunately this produces horrible outputs when it comes to heatmaps:

[image]

- The text in the legend overlaps
- The labels are cut off

I generate the heatmap with the following command:

```
heatmap.2(hmap, col = redgreen(256), trace="none", symbreaks=T, dendrogram="row", Colv = FALSE, denscol="grey")
```

How can I improve this output? I am not very familiar with the `pdf()` command.

Comment: You can use `margin=c(10,10)` (say) to make you labels appear fully.

Comment: I noticed the same thing with RStudio's PDF Export and heat maps. `pdf()` works better, and it's quite easy: `pdf("FileName.pdf") ; heatmap(...) ; dev.off()`. You can toy with `width=...` and `height...` in `pdf()`, I usually do 8 and 10.